# Call a boostrap .close button - alert.js

Tags: jquery, button, alert

I am trying to call all .close buttons in jQuery. But it's not working.

in html

```
<a id="clear" style="display: none;">clear</a>
<ul id="file-list">
    <li class="alert">
        <div id="file-name">file1.txt</div>
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert"></button>
    </li>
    <li class="alert">
        <div id="file-name">file2.txt</div>
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert"></button>
    </li>  
    <li class="alert">
        <div id="file-name">file3.txt</div>
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert"></button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

in jQuery,

```
$('#clear').click(function() {
    $(button).alert('close');
});
```

What I am missing? Thanks.

Comment: how can you click a with id clear if it is display none? hmmm

Comment: guradio, it might be shown in javascript not provided here....

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$('#clear').click(function(e) {
    //prevent the A from doing what it would normally do
    e.preventDefault();
    //selects all buttons with close class, and click them
    $('button.close').click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in bootstrap you have to change data-dismiss="alert" to data-dismiss="modal"

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-default " data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>`

try this line